# Read image and MKAnnotation from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

What could be wrong??Name and bool value gets loaded but image and coordinates no.All the values are stored in plist I checked it.Thanks for advice

```
-(NSDictionary *)makePropertyListDictionary{
        NSMutableDictionary *plistTrick = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.trickPhoto,0.8);
        if(data){
            [plistTrick setObject:data forKey:@"image"];
        }
        [plistTrick setObject:self.trickName forKey:@"name"];
        [plistTrick setObject:@(self.pinNotation.coordinate.latitude) forKey:@"latitude"];
        [plistTrick setObject:@(self.pinNotation.coordinate.longitude) forKey:@"longtitude"];
        [plistTrick setObject:@(self.landed) forKey:@"landed"];
        return plistTrick;
        }


-(void)readPlistDictionary:(NSDictionary *)trickFormPlist
{
    NSArray *imageArray = [trickFormPlist objectForKey:@"image"];
    if(self.trickPhoto){
    self.trickPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    self.landed = [[trickFormPlist valueForKey:@"landed"]intValue];
    self.trickName = [trickFormPlist objectForKey:@"name"];
    double latitude = [[trickFormPlist objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [[trickFormPlist objectForKey:@"longtitude"]doubleValue];
    self.pinNotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

}
```

Comment: Add your json data snippet..

Comment: Code is storing the image as NSData but then retrieving the same key as if it was an NSArray of NSStrings of the image name.  How did you test that the coordinates are being saved properly and how did you check the values that are being read back?

Comment: I am working only with plist....NSLog(@"%@",plistArray)
there's code for image
landed = 1;
        latitude = "48.72999760981713";
        longtitude = "21.23446137715118";
        name = " Nollie Crooked BigSpin";
    },